# Does Hilbert Transform commute with Function Multiplication modulo Compact on $L^p(R)$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, operator-theory

Define Hilbert Transform (HT) as the convolution with the function $1/x$. E. Stein proves in his book 
**Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions**
that HT, when understood as a singular integral operator, is a bounded operator on $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ for $p\in (1, \infty)$.

I am wondering if HT has compact commutator with multiplication by $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ on $L^p(\mathbb{R})$?

More precisely, if $T \in \mathscr{L}(L^p(\mathbb{R}))$ denotes the Hilbert transform, and $f \in C_0(\mathbb{R})$, is it true that $Tf - fT \in \mathbb{K}(L^p(\mathbb{R}))$? If it is true, would you please give me a reference? Thank you!

P.S: cross-posted from MSE here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676833/does-hilbert-transform-commute-with-function-multiplication-modulo-compact-on-l

Comment: Does not look likely to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem reduces to the case of smooth functions with compact support, since they are norm dense in $C_0$.

Now let $f$ be a smooth function with compact support. Then $[T,f]$ is an integral operator with smooth kernel $k(x,y) := (f(x)-f(y))/(x-y)$.

There is an [easy to check sufficient condition](http://www2.math.umd.edu/~lvrmr/2008-2009-S/Classes/AMSC674/IntOps.pdf) for compactness of integral operators from $L^p$ to $L^q$ in terms of iterated norms: namely, if an integral operator with kernel $k$ has finite norm $\left[ \intop \left( \intop |k(x,y)|^{p^\ast} dy \right)^{q/p^\ast} dx \right]^{1/q}$, $1/p+1/p^\ast = 1$, then the operator is compact from $L^p$ to $L^q$. This condition is obviously satisfied by our kernel.

Comment: Are smooth functions dense in the *operator* norm?

Comment: Eh, this was not a very good comment.

Comment: By the way, I am convinced now.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for your reply. Two questions: a) Is the operator norm of "multiplied by $f$" operator bounded by its  sup (or $L^\infty$ norm)?  b) For the case of $f$ smooth and cptly supported, can we use the fact that $k(x, y)$ can be approximated in sup norm by $\sum_i g_i(x)h_i(y)$? If so, is the operator norm of the "difference kernel" bounded by its sup norm? Thanks!

Comment: a) The operator norm of multiplication by $f$ equals the $L^\infty$ norm of $f$.

b) The sup norm of the kernel on $\mathbb{R}$ doesn't bound the operator norm, since not all bounded kernels correspond to bounded operators. However, the decomposition into a sum of rank-ones is certainly useful for the "$\mathrm{supp} f \times \mathrm{supp} f$ block" of the kernel, if you view it as a "block matrix" corresponding to $L^p(\mathbb{R}) \simeq L^p(\mathrm{supp} f) \oplus L^p(\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathrm{supp} f)$. On that block this decomposition actually converges fast enough to ensure that

Comment: the block is nuclear. I don't know how to write a nice decomposition globally on $\mathbb{R}$